# Total summary from a sales table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am new for development. I have a table in Oracle named `tbl_sale`. I have placed the table structure below and i also placed the exact report what i want.Please help me to get this. I want to show the record where parent=0;

**tbl_sale**

```
ID  AMOUNT  PARENT
1   100     0
2   125.26  1
3   11      1
4   200     0
5   500     4
6   250     4
7   100     4
8   29      0
```

Desired output:

```
ID  AMOUNT  PARENT
1   236.26  0
4   1050    0
8   29      0
```

Comment: explain what are columns in your output table and what's your goal?.

Comment: Can you explain more what your report suppose to do? it's just not making any sense, are you trying to get mean, average, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I get it, Sum of parent ID's by ID. so for ID 1 it's sum of 100+125.6+11

Comment: see my updaated question

Comment: Do you need both an SQL Server annd Oracle solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way both in SQL Server and Oracle by leveraging a recursive CTE

```
WITH q(id, amount, parent, top_most) AS 
(
  SELECT id, amount, parent, id 
    FROM tbl_sale 
   WHERE parent = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.amount, t.parent, q.id
    FROM tbl_sale t JOIN q 
      ON t.parent = q.id
)
SELECT top_most id, SUM(amount), MIN(parent) parent
  FROM q
 GROUP BY top_most
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | SUM(AMOUNT) | PARENT |
|----|-------------|--------|
|  1 |      236.26 |      0 |
|  4 |        1050 |      0 |
|  8 |          29 |      0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd5f7/1)** demo (**Oracle**)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1078a/1)** demo (**SQL Server**)

Answer (score 1):

This is what aggregate function and a `GROUP BY` are designed for:

```
SELECT   id, SUM(amount) AS amount, parent
FROM     tbl_sale
WHERE    parent = 0
GROUP BY id, parent
```

Comment: This won't produce desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You you are trying to sum based on the sequence of the source data, which is not guaranteed and is subject to change.
You need to redesign `tbl_sale` to include an element which is common to the rows that you are trying group.

```
tbl_sale_line_tems

ID  AMOUNT  PARENT  sale_id  
1   100.00       0        1
2   125.26       1        1
3    11.00       1        1
4   200.00       0        2
5   500.00       4        2
6   250.00       4        2
7   100.00       4        2
8    29.00       0        3
```

We could now also infer that the parent line-item (0) always has the lowest ID within the group of line items for the sale.

```
select min(ID) as ID
      ,sum(amount)
      ,sale_id
  from tbl_sale_line_items
 group by sale_id;

ID   AMOUNT  SALE_ID
 1   236.26        1
 4  1050.00        2
 8    29.00        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it

```
SELECT 
  parent_id,
  sum(amount)
FROM
  ( SELECT 
      case when ts2.id IS NULL then ts1.id else ts2.id end as parent_id,
      ts1.amount
    FROM 
      tbl_sale ts1
      LEFT JOIN tbl_sale ts2 ON ( ts1.parent = ts2.id )
  )
GROUP BY
  parent_id
ORDER BY
  parent_id
```